# VBA Macro Compare dates to take the earliest

Tags: excel, vba

I have list of vendors with dates of creation below, I can have up to 3 dates but I need the earliest one from today (so the latest since begin of times lol). "dates" are no actual date values but strings, like Vendors number, thats why I try to Format them.

First I tried to put colors to identify it but it doesnt work... I cannot compare dates: how to do?

I have used this but it seems to not work properly...

```vb
D1 = Format(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, 1).Value, "dd.mm.yy")
```

```vb
Sub douzemois()
Dim FL1 As Worksheet, Cell As Range, NoCol As Integer
Dim NoLig As Long, DerLig As Long, Var As Variant
    Set FL1 = Worksheets("Feuil1")
    NoCol = 1

    For NoLig = 1 To 8
        Var = FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)
        'len var <> 10 is vendor
        If Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)) <> 10 Then
            'one date only
            If Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, NoCol)) <> 10 Then
                FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol + 1) = FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)
                FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol + 2) = FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, NoCol)
            'mote than one date
            ElseIf Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, NoCol)) = 10 Then
                D1 = Format(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, 1).Value, "dd.mm.yy")
                'two dates only
                If Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 3, NoCol)) <> 10 Then
                    If D1 < Format(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, 1).Value, "dd.mm.yy") Then
                        FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                    Else
                        FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                    End If
                'three dates
                Else
                    D2 = Format(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, 1).Value, "dd.mm.yy")
                    D3 = Format(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 3, 1).Value, "dd.mm.yy")

                    If D1 < D2 Then
                        If D2 < D3 Then
                            FL1.Cells(NoLig + 3, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                        Else
                            FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                        End If
                    Else
                        If D1 < D3 Then
                            FL1.Cells(NoLig + 3, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set FL1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Feuil1 is

```
20563
21.04.1999
20540
23.10.2000
25.02.1999
20558
07.03.2001
30.01.2004
28.12.1999
```

Result is

> 21.04.1999 ; 25.02.1999 ; 28.12.1999

Result must be

> 21.04.1999 ; 23.10.2000 ; 30.01.2004

I will then format the result like this

```
Col1  | Col2
20563 | 21.04.1999
20540 | 23.10.2000
20558 | 30.01.2004
```

Comment: Are your column's 1 Cells set as date ?

Comment: No I cannot, I have also the numbers of Vendors thats why I use Format() in code

Comment: The **earliest** date of these three dates `07.03.2001`, `30.01.2004` and `28.12.1999` actually is `28.12.1999` not  `30.01.2004`

Comment: Earliest from today I meant

Comment: You probably mean the **latest**. You should [edit] your question to clarify that. Latest date is the greatest not the smallest so `28.12.1999  <  07.03.2001  <  30.01.2004`

Comment: okay thanks, so I have tried with  Format but it doesn"t select the right date

Comment: because if you use `Format()` it returns a string and you cannot calculate with strings like `D1 < D2`. You need to use the numerical date for that. `Dim D1 As Date, D2 As Date, …` and don't use `Format()`.

Comment: Do you mean this ? It triggers an error "waiting end of instruction" D1 As Date = FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, 1).Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. It loops through all data in column A and for all non-dates it checks the following 3 cells to find the latest date.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindLatestDate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long, jRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow
        If Not IsDate(ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value) Then 'current is number not a date
            'check how many dates we have below
            For jRow = iRow + 1 To iRow + 3 'max 3 dates
                If Not IsDate(ws.Cells(jRow, "A").Value) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next jRow

            'output
            ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value = Application.Max(ws.Range(ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "A"), ws.Cells(jRow - 1, "A")))
            iRow = jRow - 1 'jump to next non-date
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Format the column B as date and the output will be (depending on your desired date format)

[image]

---

Edit according comments:

You can run the following to convert your data into real dates before finding the latest date.

```
Public Sub ConvertIntoRealDates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long, DateOfString As Variant
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow
        DateOfString = GetDateOfString(ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value)
        If Not IsError(DateOfString) Then
            ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = DateOfString
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub

'convert string `dd.mm.yyyy` into a real date otherwise return error
Private Function GetDateOfString(ByVal Value As String) As Variant
    Dim DateArr As Variant
    DateArr = Split(Value, ".")

    If UBound(DateArr) = 2 Then 'is a date
        GetDateOfString = DateSerial(DateArr(2), DateArr(1), DateArr(0))
    Else
        GetDateOfString = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output is not what expected : 
```
20563| 20563 /
28.12.1999| 20540 /
20540| 20540 /
23.10.2000| 0 /
28.12.1999| 20558 /
20558| 20558 /
07.03.2001| 0 /
28.12.1999| 0 /
30.01.2004| 20559```

Comment: @Dng Format the column B as date!

Comment: I mean I have vendors instead of dates ```20563 18/04/1956
28.12.1999 26/03/1956
20540 26/03/1956
23.10.2000 00/01/1900
28.12.1999 13/04/1956
20558 13/04/1956
07.03.2001 00/01/1900
28.12.1999 00/01/1900
30.01.2004 14/04/1956
```
My initial dates remain with dd.mm.yyyy in Standard format because I cannot format the column without formating vendors also which i dont want

Comment: @Dng So are you saying your "dates" are no actual date values but strings?

Comment: Yes they are, same as Vendors, that's why I tried to Format them

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (for more than 3 dates!!). Thanks for the trick @Pᴇʜ

```vb
Sub douzemois()
Dim FL1 As Worksheet, Cell As Range, NoCol As Integer
Dim NoLig As Long, DerLig As Long, Var As Variant
    Set FL1 = Worksheets("Feuil1")
    NoCol = 1

    For NoLig = 1 To 41711
        Var = FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)
        'len var <> 10 is vendor
        If Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)) <> 10 Then
            'one date only
            If Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, NoCol)) <> 10 Then
                FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol + 1) = FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)
                FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol + 2) = GetDateOfString(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, NoCol))
            'more than one date
            ElseIf Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 2, NoCol)) = 10 Then
                maxtempdate = GetDateOfString(FL1.Cells(NoLig + 1, NoCol))
                For i = 1 To 400
                    If Len(FL1.Cells(NoLig + i, NoCol)) <> 10 Then
                        FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol + 1) = FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol)
                        FL1.Cells(NoLig, NoCol + 2) = maxtempdate
                        i = 400
                    ElseIf GetDateOfString(FL1.Cells(NoLig + i, NoCol)) > maxtempdate Then
                        maxtempdate = GetDateOfString(FL1.Cells(NoLig + i, NoCol))
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set FL1 = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function GetDateOfString(ByVal Value As String) As Variant
    Dim DateArr As Variant
    DateArr = Split(Value, ".")

    If UBound(DateArr) = 2 Then 'is a date
        GetDateOfString = DateSerial(DateArr(2), DateArr(1), DateArr(0))
    Else
        GetDateOfString = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End Function
```